# WPF Pass object from window's Usercontrol to another window's Usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have 2 windows and 2 user controls the first window uses the first user control to display brief info about objects in a listview, now when the user clicks on an object(row) from the list the second window should open with the second user control showing the full info of that object.

So the problem is how I can pass that object from UC1 to UC2.

Comment: Hello, Perhaps this could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69223447/4095782

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your problem is to use MVVM. For example:

List Window:

```
<Window>
    <ItemsControl ItemSource = {Binding DataItems}>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <userControls:YourLessDetailedUserControl/>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Window>
```

Detail Window:

```
<Window>
         <userControls:YourMoreDetailedUserControl DataContext = {Binding DataItem}/>
</Window>
```

ViewModels:

```
class MainWindowViewModel
{
     public List<DataItemViewModel> DataItems {get;}
}

class DataItemViewModel
{
     public ICommand OpenInDetailedWindow {get;}

     //more properties here to describe your data item
}

class DetailedWindowViewModel
{
    DataItemViewModel DataItem {get;}
}
```

The `ICommand` in the `DataItemViewModel` should be defined to open the Detail Window with `DetailedWindowViewModel.DataItem` set to that `DataItemViewModel`.

If you are new to MVVM this will all look pretty foreign. That's ok though! It's hard for everyone at first.